# IOS facebook integration like button 

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, facebook-like

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"hello", @"name",
                                   @"This post has been liked.", @"caption",
                                   Post, @"description",
                                   @"http://www.abc.com/", @"link",
                                   @"http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/49ncw.png", @"picture",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                   nil];


    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

The post its getting published at my wall succesfully , But i want it to be liked at the same time when its gets published.and that will increase the like count.
please help